# Entity Framework Designer First get navigation property as Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await

The Task pattern says that in order to be consistent everything has to be completely async or completely not async.

By using entity framework designer first I can achieve this quite easily

```
var course = await db.Courses.FindAsync(CourseID);
```

Courses is a DbSet generated by entity framework and therefore has all the Async methods.
The problem is that if I add a navigation property to that class, the latter is not a DbSet and it does not contain any async method definition.

As an example, if I add a navigation property to a Students table, it will be created as a virtual ICollection Students
which means I cannot use the async methods.
But what I do want is having entity framework to automatically generate a Task<> in order to be able to await even the navigation properties.

Is It possible? my goal is to achieve something like this:

```
var course = await db.Courses.FindAsync(CourseID);
var student = await course.Students.FindAsync(StudentID);
```

while at the moment my options are mixing async/notAsync code:

```
var course = await db.Courses.FindAsync(CourseID);
var student = course.Students.First(p => p.ID = StudentID);
```

or not using the navigation property at all:

```
var course = await db.Courses.FindAsync(CourseID);
var student = await db.Students.Where(p => p.CourseID == course.ID && p.ID == StudentsID).FirstAsync();
```

Can you suggest a solution that do not require code first?

**EDIT**
according to https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#AsyncLazyLoading what im searching for is called "Async Lazy Loading" and is not a feature available yet (and maybe it will never be).
It seems that you can either use Lazy Loading OR the async features, maybe I should just wrap the property in a Task by awaiting Task.Run(course.Students.First(p => p.ID = StudentID)) but I'm not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: What is the declared type of `Students`? Where does the `Students.Find` method come from?

Comment: Sry Jean, there wasnt a Find method. I edited the question thanks. The Students class is another class generated by EF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, lazy loading (which would in my opinion be the case where enumerating the navigation property would trigger a database access) is a bad access pattern, as it simply means that database access will happen at surprising places, which can make application performance difficult to predict.

All the solutions below use an import from `System.Data.Entity`.

**Solution 1**: Use eager loading with an `Include`

```
var course = await db.Courses.Include(c => c.Students).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ID == CourseID);
var student = course.Students.First(p => p.ID == StudentID);
```

Advantages:

- One database access that is required to load all objects - and this solution scales very well if you want to retrieve more than one `Course` object at a time;
- The `Students` navigation property is loaded and can be used freely;

Drawbacks:

- There is always at least one database access;
- The whole set of related `Student` objects is loaded even if you needed only one;

**Solution 2**: Use the `LoadAsync` method that exists on the concrete collection class;

This solution relies on the fact that lazy-loaded collections are from the [`EntityCollection<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn159765.aspx) class.

First, I would define an extension method:

```
public static async Task LoadAsync<T>(ICollection<T> collection)
    where T : class
{
    if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

    var entityCollection = collection as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<T>;

    if (entityCollection == null || entityCollection.IsLoaded) return;
    await entityCollection.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Then you could write something like:

```
var course = await db.Courses.FindAsync(CourseID);
await course.Students.LoadAsync();
var student = course.Students.First(p => p.ID = StudentID);
```

Advantage:

- There may be no database access at all if the objects are already loaded in the context;
- The navigation property `Students` is guaranteed to be loaded;

Drawbacks:

- Susceptible to the "N+1 queries" issue;
- Both the `Course` and the set of related `Student` objects can grow stale, which may trigger concurrency issues down the road; (note that concurrency issues that affect a relationship are harder to resolve than concurrency issues that affect a single record)

**Solution 3**: <s>Use the `CreateSourceQuery` method on the concrete class to load only the `Student` object that you want.</s>

OK, doing that does not work, and actually is a pretty bad idea.

However, a solution with the same advantages/drawbacks can be written, but in another way:

```
var course = await db.Courses.FindAsync(CourseID);
var studentsQuery = from c in db.Courses
                    where c.ID == CourseID
                    from s in c.Students
                    select s;
var student = await studentsQuery.FirstAsync(p => p.ID = StudentID);
```

Advantage:

- You only load the one `Student` object that you are going to use;

Drawbacks:

- The `Students` navigation property is not loaded, meaning that it cannot be used without potentially triggering a database access;
- The second line will always trigger a database access (susceptible to the "N+1 queries" issue, or even running the method times);

**Solution 4**: Eager loading, more selective: load both the course and the student that interest you in the initial LINQ query.

I am not 100% sure that that solution will work as written.

```
var query = from c in db.Courses
            where c.ID == CourseID
            select new { course = c, student = c.Students.First(p => p.ID == StudentID) };

var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var course = result.course;
var student = result.student;
```

Advantages:

- Only one database access is required to retrieve both objects;
- You only retrieve the objects that you are going to work on;

Drawbacks:

- The `Students` navigation property is not loaded, meaning that it cannot be used without potentially triggering a database access;

** When to use which solution? **

- If you need the navigation property to be filled (either because you know that you will make use of most of its elements, or because you want to pass the parent entity to another component that is allowed to make use of that property however it wants), then use solution 1 or 2;
- If you do not need the navigation property to be filled, then use solution 4. Only use solution 3 if you categorically have the `Course` object already loaded;

Comment: The only but perfect solution to me could be the third one but I had quite a few problems:

Comment: The only but perfect solution to me could be the third one but it isnt working: the casting to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<T> always return null => always return collection.AsQueryable()  => awaiting the result cause this exception: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user cod
Additional information: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Simone: I did not know that the `*Async` LINQ methods had additional requirements. And now that I think about it, exposing multiple `IQueryable` implementations indistinguishably (such as is done in the `CreateSourceQuery` extension method) is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to await the course and then get the students without awaiting it?  Im pretty sure I shouldnt mix async and notasync code, but im not sure what problems I would encounter (except of course loosing the async benefits). It seems that navigation properties are completely useless with async code in entity framework

Comment: @Simone: When I had last looked at the Entity Framework code, I am pretty sure that running multiple queries on a given `DbContext` at the same time was disallowed - so that idea would not work.

Comment: @Simone: And every program will mix asynchronous and synchronous code: synchronous code is perfectly appropriate for any short-lived operation, or when there is no problem if the thread that you use would be busy for a long time, and asynchronous code is a fit for the case where the thread under use is precious (e.g. the UI thread, or any thread on a server that wants to scale as highly as possible) and the asynchronous call consumes resources that are of less value than the current thread.

Comment: @Simone: However, the fundamental tension that you experience here is because there is a fundamental tension between "lazily-loaded navigation properties", that seek to give convenience to the programmer at the price of control, and doing things asynchronously, the only motivation for which is to control these resources.

Comment: @Simone: I guess I did not notify you that I have changed solution 3 to something that I think *should* work.

Comment: The new solution does not use navigation property (students containes "where c.ID == CourseID") so it can't be an answer to my question.

Comment: @Simone: The new solution *does* use the navigation property, in the query context (`c.Students` is the navigation property). To the point, I know of two ways to use a navigation property - one way is to use it as an in-memory representation of related entities, which requires that it be loaded (solutions 1 and 2). The other way is to use it as a way of representing a query on related objects without repeating the way that the join is made (`c.Students` in the query context), as in solutions 3 and 4. `CreateSourceQuery` is nothing more than a way to get the associated query from the object.