# Async methods on ICollection with EF6

Tags: asynchronous, entity-framework-6

My domain objects define collections as `virtual ICollection<type>`. I want to use async methods in my repositories and services but it is not available.

How do I use async methods on my EF properties?

Comment: Async on your properties?  Can you show an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Brendan, in this case it's a lazy load collection and I don't want the thread to block while it reads from the database.

Comment: I don't think you want that to happen - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766025/entity-framework-designer-first-get-navigation-property-as-tasks