# How to query an entity's collection property asynchronously

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My question does not have to do with asynchronously querying collection properties of subclasses of DbContext but to do with querying collection properties of entities.

Let's assume we have the situation as given by [Async Query & Save (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx).

If we consider the class Blog, which looks like this:

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

How to asynchronously query the Posts collection, for instance something like:

```
await someBlog.Posts.Where(p => p.Title == ...).ToListAsync()
```

The problem however is, that ToListAsync() is not a part of the List<> class and System.Data.Entity does not define a ToListAsync() extension method.

Therefore, how to query collection properties asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Async loading of navigation properties [is not supported in EF 6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#AsyncLazyLoading).

There is a set of workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766025/entity-framework-designer-first-get-navigation-property-as-tasks).