# use ToListAsync() with navigation property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework.
I have an entity called "AllUserData". 
I have a second entity called "Genres". Each row in the table is a genre.

These two entities have a one-to-many relationship. So in the class definition of the "AllUserData" class, I have 
  public virtual ICollection PreferredGenres { get; set; }

I am able to successfully read the genres preferred by each user using

```
AllUserData aud = db.AllUserData.Single(b => b.UserId == currentUserId);
var chosengenres = aud.PreferredGenres.ToList()
```

However I cannot use

```
AllUserData aud = db.AllUserData.Single(b => b.UserId == currentUserId);
var chosengenres = await aud.PreferredGenres.ToListAsync()
```

Visual Studio says "ICollection does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'.

Why is this happening? The only difference between the two was that in one case I used ToList() and in the other I used ToListAsync().

Can async methods not be used with navigation properties? In a real life application there are many cases where there are relationships between various entities; can asynchronous methods not be used when accessing properties using these relationships? Is there some way around this? I'd rather do things asynchronously if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems entity framework doesn't allow for calling the navigation property asynchronously in this manner.

What worked for me is earger loading the navigation property in the beginning. (Thanks to user daf for sending me in the correct direction).

So instead of

```
AllUserData aud = await db.AllUserData.SingleAsync(b => b.UserId == currentUserId);
var usergenres = await aud.PreferredGenres.ToListAsync();
```

which does not work, I can instead do this :

```
AllUserData aud = await db.AllUserData.Include(p=>p.PreferredGenres).SingleAsync(b => b.UserId == currentUserId);
var usergenres = aud.PreferredGenres.ToList();
```

This way the first query asks to pull all necessary information from the database through eager loading with .Include(), and does so asynchronously due to the user of .SingleAsync(). The next statement uses .ToList(), but shouldn't make a second trip to the database since the data is already eager loaded, so it doesn't matter that it is async. The whole operation is now async.

I also realized this same question has been asked previously on StackOverflow; it is a little difficult to find depending on what search terms you used: [Entity Framework Designer First get navigation property as Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766025/entity-framework-designer-first-get-navigation-property-as-tasks). The selected answer provides 4 different solutions, out of which the first one is similar to what I am using now.

It also appears possible to designate navigation properties as async when defining the entity class- see the section titled "Async Lazy Loading" on this page: [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.)  The sample snippet demonstrates how to do this for a single navigation property; I don't know if it can be done for an ICollection navigation property as well, which is what I need, but I didn't do any further digging either.

Answer (score 2):

Your navigation property would have been declared as an ICollection, standard for Entity properties -- the compiler won't be pleased.

However, you can get an IQueryable with AsQueryable or with another Select() (if that makes sense for your needs) between the navigation collection and the ToListAsync().

ToList() can operate on IEnumerable (which includes ICollection and IQueryable). ToListAsync() has only been made to work with IQueryable, hence the message from VS. The "why" may lie in the implementation details.

Comment: In particular, the use of IQueryable means that ToListAsync doesn't have to wait for the query to be executed at the server and return -- which is kind of the point: you're asking it to run your query in the background and come back to the current spot in code when it completes.

Comment: I actually tried "await aud.PreferredGenres.AsQueryable().ToListAsync()" prior to posting here. Although VS did not complain, when I actually tried running it it raised an exception at runtime. For whatever reason that doesn't seem to work either. You said an alternative might be to use a Select(). You mean I should call it before ToListAsync()?

Comment: FYI, the error received when I used AsQueryable().ToListAsync() was - "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<MatildaMVCWebsite.Models.Genre>. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068."

Comment: Yeah, the problem may be that the query has already been resolved;perhaps try:

`AllUserData aud = await db.AllUserData.Single(b => b.UserId == currentUserId).Select(u => u.PreferredGenres).ToListAsync();`

Which allows the entire query to happen at the server.

Comment: That doesn't work either unfortunately. I get this message - "AllUserData does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' acepting a first argument of type 'AllUserData' could be found"

Comment: I think I have a solution. You helped me go in the correct direction, since the problem is that the first query has already been resolved. I'm going to test it out and will post if it works.

Comment: *facepalm* I just noticed that you were doing `db.AllUserData.Single`. For some reason, my brain saw `Where`. If you were do to the above with `Where`, it would work -- it also would just return an empty list if the user weren't found, where the `Single` and `SingleAsync` routes will throw if the user isn't found (or if the user data is duplicated) -- which may be what you want, but it's good to be aware of it (: